# update of an android application

Tags: android

Could someone explain in technical details how an android application handles updates ? . What kind of information does the application usually needs to send to request an update , and what does it receives back ? .

Answer (score 5):

Updates to applications themselves are handled centrally by the Market application. You upload your updated apk to the Market via the website, and your users will be prompted to upgrade over the next couple of days.

This is why it is **very important** to retain your .keystore file with which you sign your apps. If you don't have this signature, you cannot update your apps for security reasons.

Your application doesn't need to contain any update logic of its own.

Comment: klaud-vlad: this is also why the rest of your questions cannot be answered -- the Android Market is not open source, so we do not know all of what it does.

Comment: You can do that. A user can install a link from a standard http web link to an apk file. On the first occasion their device will prompt them to enable the 'Non-Market Applications' options in the preferences, but this is quite straightforward. You could easily call a web service from your app to find out if a newer version is available and to direct users to download it via the Android Browser. One advantage of this approach is some control over upgrade rate rather than the 'big bang' approach which is all that is supported by the Market.

Comment: Super, that's pretty much what I want to do. When the user hits the "check for updates" button, a checking for new updates through a server request is performed, and if there are , and the user agrees to update , the updating process should begin. For this ,is it sufficient to have back from the server , the link for downloading the apk ?

Comment: ..are there any other information mandatory the server should send back ?

Comment: No it can be super-simple. I'd send an http request to my service (perhaps an App Engine service), something like `http://example.com/update.jsp?versionCode=3` where the versionCode comes from the manifest version. Then I would have the service either return blank (no update) or a URL to which the user should be directed to get the new apk.

Comment: So the user receives the url (available updates), and uses the Android browser to download  the apk on the mmc from the provided link. Can you describe what should happen further with the new downloaded apk ? , should it be used by the apps installer ?

Comment: More specifically I mean how the new apk and the installed application  are combined ?

Comment: You trigger a new intent to visit the URL. The user then gets sent to the browser which downloads the apk.

Comment: @Adam `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode`